# Why does my google sheet think it's in GMT 0:00?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form (from JotForm actually) putting dates into a spreadsheet:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFD7k.png)

The sheet settings show that it is in GMT -05:00.
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHvU8.png)

The date in the last row is "3/20/2023 16:30:00" (copied from the formula bar).

My script gets the date from the last row:

```
var newEventTime = new Date(ss.getSheetValues(lastRow, dateColumn, 1, 1));
```

When I log the date, it comes out as:

> Mon Mar 20 2023 12:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

The script timezone is also in GMT -05:00.
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z7j2.png)

It seems the dates listed are being taken as times in GMT 00:00 and thus displayed 4 hours earlier. Why??

**Okay, more info that might help:
In a row that shows this time in the cell: 2023-03-08 8:00:00 PM
This is what shows up in the formula bar: 3/8/2023 20:00:00
When I do ss.getSheetValues(lastRow, 16, 1, 1) it returns this: [ [ Wed Mar 08 2023 15:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) ] ]
Does that tell us anything about what the problem is?

Comment: What is the spreadsheet timezone?

Comment: Same - GMT -05:00. I mentioned this and it is shown in image #2.

Comment: I tried your scenario and it worked perfectly on my end; have you tried refreshing your browser or opening the sheets and apps script on incognito as this could be a caching issue? Additionally, check that the code is correctly fetching the value from the cell in the sheet where you have the date stored.

Comment: Tried all these things. Still has the time wrong.

Comment: Ok, so to make this work I've been fetching the event start time from the spreadsheet and adding 5 hours. Now with the time change I had to change it to 4 hours because when it ran this morning it produced a result that was one hour off! Any other ideas?

Comment: I suspect the 1 hour off was due to [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) . The DST for the year 2023 started last March 12,2023.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. But I still have to offset it 4 hours. It's giving me a time at GMT 0 not GMT -4. I don't know why.

Comment: Have you tried `Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)` in rendering the date to a particular format and timezone? Further example can be seen [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates#basic_concepts).

Comment: Yes. This is what I have to do to make it work:
var newEventTime = new Date(ss.getSheetValues(lastRow, 16, 1, 1));
var startTime = new Date(newEventTime.getTime() + fourHour);
var apptTime = Utilities.formatDate(startTime, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'hh:mm a');

Comment: Figured something out: if I use to_text to turn the date in the spreadsheet into a string and add GMT -5 at the end, then get THAT to make the date, it works. Just need to figure out how to make that work in my script.

Answer (score 1):

Did a little research on this.  The timestamp on the Google Sheet is populated by Jotform's timezone settings not by your Google Sheets settings.

From Jotform:

> The timestamp in the Google Spreadsheet is displayed based on the timezone set on your Jotform account. Please make sure that you are having the correct timezone set on your Jotform account settings.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Comment: Modified as requested.

Comment: Not really. You still more or less ask a question instead of giving a solution. Please do the "if .. then ... because ...." pattern. Or to put it differently, if not correct then what? And why? Also, how to recognise incorrect? Compare [answer], to see the goal for an answer post. The conditional answer pattern is for the time you do not have the commenting privilege yet - which is not far away, good luck with that; you will get there.

Comment: Modified again.  Did some further research to be able to eliminate the "I believe" clause.

Comment: I see, I mistook your quote for you yourself saying "make sure".... I think this looks like an answer now instead of a question or check-proposal. Thanks for your patience. :-)

Comment: No problem.  I am used to asking the questions, not providing answers.  This is something I was struggling with before, so thought I would share what I have learned.

Comment: "Sharing what you learned" is pretty much exactly the goal of StackOverflow - squeezed into the Q/A format however.

Comment: Timezone in JotForm is correct.